# Chrome extension changing popup.html text

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I'm a complete novice, i want to take a text from a "p" tag and put it in another "p" tag so when i click on my extension i see the two texts being displayed. 
What i'm doing wrong? and how can i avoid similar mistakes in the future?

popup.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
      <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" scr= "popup.js"></script>
      </head>
      <body>            
        <p id="firstText">this is the text to be repeated</p> 
        <p id= "secondText"></p>        
     </body>   
</html>
```

popup.js:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {

 var test= document.getElementById("firstText").innerHTML;
 document.getElementById("secondText").innerHTML=test;

});
```

manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "test",
  "description": "useless",
  "version": "1.0",
   "background": {
      "scripts": [ "popup.js"],
      "persistent": false
   }, 
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*"],  
      "js": ["popup.js"]
    }
    ], 
    "permissions": [
    "activeTab","tabs", "http://*/*"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

Comment: If this is an exact copy / paste, you have a typo in  `<script type="text/javascript" scr= "popup.js"></script>`. It should read `src` instead of `scr`.

Comment: @ChrisP I'm so embarrassed, thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this HTML for popup: **you are having typo mistake** `src`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
      <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src= "popup.js"></script>
      </head>
      <body>            
        <p id="firstText">this is the text to be repeated</p> 
        <p id= "secondText"></p>        
     </body>   
</html>
```

Comment: I'm using sublimetext2, i didn't see that, i spent 24 searching the internet and changing the code, i even tried jquery functions on it to try and load the DOM before the Js ^^" so really really thank you! i don't have enough reputation to vote you up, but i will comeback to it promise =)