# Write to HTML Element from JavaScript Function

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I have a JavaScript file where I am using a Chrome Extension to gather data aboout a webpage, and I would like to display it in a `popup`. I'm new to web development and am having trouble determining the best way to send this page information as text from my `.js` file to my `.html` file upon some event listener executing. the element I was trying to write to was `output1`.

**popup.js**

```
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(function (tab) {
  chrome.tabs.query({
  active: true,
  currentWindow: true
  },
  function (tabs) {
    var tab = tabs[0];
    var id = tab.id;
    var url = tab.url;
    var title = tab.title;
    var host = new URL(url).hostname;
    console.log("id: " + id + "\nurl:" + url + "\nhost:" + host + "\ntitle: " + title);
  output1.text = host;
  });
});
```

**popup.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h3>Domain output</h3>
    <output name="output1"></output>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: There's no such property as `text` in most elements. You probably meant `textContent`. Also assuming the popup is a browserAction popup, the onActivated listener won't work because the popup runs only when shown and destroyed when hidden on tab switch - you either don't need this listener altogether or you need to rework the extension to use a background script and a different method of indication. Make sure to study the architecture article in the documentation.

Comment: Got it, and you're right. I was having difficulty finding the right event listener as `chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function callback)` does not fire if the `browser_action` has a popup, which I do. For this sample I am testing, my goal is to simply display the domain in a popup window when the extension is clicked. As of now, this only works when a page is navigated to that already has a page loaded, but my goal is to have it work even when a new tab is clicked and a web address is navigated to also.

Answer (score 0):

Supposed that you've defined `manifest.json` and `popup.js` [correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19007860/chrome-extension-changing-popup-html-text) you can use either [`.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) or [`.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent):

```
var x = document.getElementsByName("output1");
x[0].innerHTML = host;
/*x[0].textContent = host;*/
```

Note that [`getElementsByName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName) is selecting all element using name you select. Which in the example was `output1`, if you had more than 1 element using the same names. Then you need to select using index from `0` like in the example in the snippet.

```js
var host = "host content";
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
 var x = document.getElementsByName("output1");
 x[0].textContent = host;
 x[1].innerHTML = "h3";
});
```

```html
<output name="output1"></output>

<h3 name="output1"></h3>
```

Comment: For some reason I am getting an error about not being able to set the innerHTML of undefined on `x[0].innerHTML = host;`

Comment: No it does not. I am logging the content with `var x = document.getElementsByName("output1").value = url; console.log("popup element to populate: " + x);` but for some reason when i click on my Extension to show the page there is nothing populated for `output1` in the UI.

Comment: I'm not sure why but it's working [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19007860/chrome-extension-changing-popup-html-text), the issue probably in the js function. Also when I'm testing there is no `innerHTML` of undefined error though. Both `.innerHTML` and `.textContent` work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using the following and used `chrome.storage.sync` to retrieve the saved value to be passed to the HTML.

**popup.js**

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
  chrome.storage.sync.get("key", function (value) {
    console.log("New key value: " + value["key"]);
    document.getElementById("outputKey").value = value["key"];
```

});
});

Answer (score -1):

you should add an id to output element and then access it through that from your js.

Update your output tag with id:

```
<output id="output1" name="output1"></output>
```

Change your assignment line in js from:

```
  output1.text = host;
```

to:

```
document.getElementById("output1").value = host;
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working using the Chrome Extension setup: "Error in response to tabs.query: TypeError: Cannot set _generated_background_page.html:1 property 'value' of null
    at Object.callback (chrome-extension://kbpcibnddgfmioggkflampdafhgkibij/popup.js:80:20)
    at chrome-extension://kbpcibnddgfmioggkflampdafhgkibij/popup.js:49:15"